# How can i close mongo connection after all db-operations done in for-each?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, mongodb-query

**Issue** :- **Db-connection** getting closed before operations done in `Node Async Programming`.

**AIM:-** Open DB Connection, Write Static Json Files in to db collections & Close connection.. before the Node server start .

**Collections :-25 and Many Documents inside so using db.insertMany()**

**Code Sample :-**

```
async function run(){
    
    try{
       let path = '../some';
       //avoiding common db configurations
        await client.connect();
        //..Couple of DB initializatoins ...
        db1.dropDataBase();
        db2.dropDataBase()

    // for reading Data from the Directory 
        fs.readDirSync(dirPath).forEach(file => {
            let collectionName = path.base(file,'.json');
            (()=>{
                if(collectionName === 'test')
                {
                 let count = await db1.collectionName.estimatedDocumentCount();
                 let jsonContent =  JSON.parse(fs.readDirSync(path.join(DirectoryPath,file),'utf-8'));
                 if(count===0){
                    await db1.collectionName.insertMany(jsonContent);
                 }
                }
                else{
                  let count = await db2.collectionName.estimatedDocumentCount();
                 let jsonContent =  JSON.parse(fs.readDirSync(path.join(DirectoryPath,file),'utf-8'));
                 if(count===0){
                    await db2.collectionName.insertMany(jsonContent);
                 }
                }
                })(file);
           })
          }
           catch(err){
              console.log('error',err);
           }
           finally
           {
            console.log('Closing DB connection');
            client.close();
           }
        
    } run().catch(console.dir);


  Output :- 
    Closing DB connection
     error cannot use a Session which is already ended 
     error cannot use a Session which is already ended 
      error cannot use a Session which is already ended
```

**Note:-** If i comment `db.close()` it works like a Charm but i cannot able to start `node app.js` since Its halted in the DB program itself.

**How can i close connection after all operations done ? i am stuck-up here :-(** Help!!

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should remove the client.close() from finally. This will be called after first loop iteration preventing you from further processing.

Then use your forEach loop to create an array of functions and use methods called Promise.all

```
var actions = [p1,p2,..] //populate this with your insert functions as promises

Promise.all().then(function() {
    // all loaded
    client.close();
}, function() {
    // one or more failed
    client.close();
});
```